# OnClick loads new HTML doc and should scroll to the bottom of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autoscroll

I'm making a simple interactive prototype consisting of different HTML documents with images and clickable div's in them to mimic the behavior of buttons in the prototype. Now I want to create the behavior of clicking a link at the top of the page which should scroll the user to the bottom of the page and show a specific part of the image (the behavior pretty much mimics remotely expanding and displaying a cell in an accordion control).

Now I've searched for JS solutions for automatically scrolling to a certain part of a markup, problem is that I don't seem to be able to find an example for how to do so when a new HTML doc is loaded.

I'm not sure if loading a new HTML does complicate things or not, but my lack of experience in web dev makes it for me seem very difficult.

This is pretty much my approach now, which doesn't work:

HTML doc 1

```
<div #akebutton style="position:relative;
    top:-1137px;
    left:410px;
    width:33px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid #000;">
        <a href="02_ake expanded.html">
            <span style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left: 0;z-index: 1;">
            </span>
        </a>

    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#akebutton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bottomDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

HTML doc 2

```
<body>
    <img src="ake expanded.png" align="middle">
    <div style="position:relative;top:-502px;left:167px;width:1069px;height:47px;border:0px solid #000;">
        <a href="01_start.html">
            <span style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left: 0;z-index: 1;">
            </span>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div id="bottomDiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="maintainscroll.jquery.min.js"></script> 

</body>
```

Comment: `<div #akebutton` it should be `<div id="akebutton"` in the html doc 1.

Comment: @Jai Thanks! That was an embarrassing error on my part. Unfortunately this didn't get it to work, which you however never said it would do. :)

Comment: Is `html anchor` a solution?

Comment: @RaraituL anchors can only be used within the same HTML doc though? No?

Comment: @AndroidHustle Hmm, no. For example, check this [link with an anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840873/onclick-loads-new-html-doc-and-should-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-it?noredirect=1#comment44085873_27840873) You will see that it automatically scrolls to your comment :)

Comment: @RaraituL Touché! :) Nice to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be this:

```
<div #akebutton style="position:relative;
```

where you have to put a valid id:

```
<div id="akebutton" style="position:relative;
```

and in the js you should use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior:

```
$("#akebutton").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // it would stop the jump of the anchor.
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#bottomDiv").offset().top
   }, 2000);
});
```

---

Note:

The `akebutton` and `bottomDiv` should be on same page as per your js code is written.

---

What seems to me you want to scroll to the loaded page, if that is the case then in the doc ready you can do this:

```
$(function(){
     var hash = location.hash;
     if(hash.length){
        $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 2000);
     }
});
```

and in your markup your anchor should pass the hash this way:

```
<a href="02_ake expanded.html#bottomDiv">
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement your alterations. The JS is however in a separate doc which is imported.

Comment: This did get the scroll to work, on the other hand it also seemed to override the loading of the new HTML doc so it scrolls to the bottom of the HTML 1 doc instead of the HTML 2 doc...

Comment: I guess the JS click event catches the click instead of the link element I have in the HTML (which loads the other HTML doc)?

Comment: Ahh, the div ID extension of the link works perfectly fine for my solution, the lack of scroll animation doesn't really bother me since it's a proof of concept rather than a product. However, if I would choose to use a JS animation instead on click then that could in your opinion be done using the last piece of JS you added in your answer?